# Equation involving complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone show me how
$$\frac{1-\bar{z}}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})}=\frac{1-\bar{z}}{2(1-Re(z))}.$$

Comment: If you did any work at all (like, perhaps, multiplying out the bottom) it would be good to include it to convince readers you made some progress :)

Comment: Do you wish to include that $|z|=1$?  If you let $z=3$, then $(1-3)(1-3)=4$, but $2(1-3)=-4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $z \in\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$:
$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1-\bar{z}}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})}=\frac{1-\bar{z}}{1-z-\bar{z}+z\bar{z}}=\frac{1-\bar{z}}{1-2\Re{z}+|z|^2},$$
therefore 
$$\frac{1-\bar{z}}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})}=\frac{1-\bar{z}}{2(1-\Re(z))}$$
if  $|z|=1.$

Comment: You should add that $z \ne 1$.

Comment: @Mercy Thanks for remark!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that $$Re(z) = \frac{z + \bar{z}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$

Cancelling the numerators we get, $\{1-(x+iy)\}\{1-(x-iy)\}=2(1-x)$

or, $(1-x)^2-(iy)^2=2-2x$

or, $x^2+y^2=1\implies \mid z\mid =1$